# Laravel 5 - Custom Guard

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So I'm using Laravel 5, and for a more complex authentication, I need to overload the method `attempt` of Laravel's Guard implementation.

However, I have trouble finding where I should replace Guard.

- Do I need to replace `Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager`, and then `Illuminate\Auth\Guard`, and change the service provider, just for one overload? This is feasible but seems heavy.
- Upon browsing `Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager`, I came to find this method:

  ```
  /**
   * Call a custom driver creator.
   *
   * @param  string  $driver
   * @return \Illuminate\Auth\Guard
   */

  protected function callCustomCreator($driver)
  {
      $custom = parent::callCustomCreator($driver);

      if ($custom instanceof Guard) return $custom;

      return new Guard($custom, $this->app['session.store']);
  }
  ```

  Any ideas where could I use it? It seems it fits perfectly my needs.

Thanks for any inputs!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the method implementation it said that you can either return instance of a `Guard` or `UserProvider` contract. So in your case you can use this code sample:

```
Auth::extend('custom', function($app)
{
    return new MyCustomGuard($userProvider, $session, $request);
}
```

Comment: Can you offer an indication of how $userProvider $session and $request should be built?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `$request` variable from the $app variable passed into the closure `$app['request']`